# Locking and signaling with Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

I know that Hazelcast locks removed manually with destroy method, and I can use IMap for locks that removed automatically. But what to do if I use conditions?

Thread 1

```
ILock lock = hazelcastInstance.getLock(transactionId);
lock.lock();
try {
   boolean signaled = lock.newCondition("someCondition").await(waitInterval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   // work 2
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Thread 2

```
ILock lock = hazelcastInstance.getLock(transactionId);
lock.lock();
try {
   // work 1
   lock.newCondition("someCondition").signalAll();
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

I can't use ILock, because I have a lot of transactions and it will cause memory leak (I can't call destroy for ILock because I don't know when I can do it). With IMap lock/unlock there is no problem with memory leak, but there I can't use ICondition.

Now I created map and two sets:

```
IMap<Long, ?> idLockingMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("idLocking");
Set<Long> waitingTrans = hazelcastInstance.getSet("waitSet");
Set<Long> signaledTrans = hazelcastInstance.getSet("notifySet");
```

Thread 1

```
//part of run method
idLockingMap.lock(transactionId);
try {
   boolean signaled = await(transactionId, 10000);
   // work 2
} finally {
    idLockingMap.unlock(transactionId);
}

private boolean await(final Long trId, long waitInterval) throws InterruptedException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    waitingTrans.add(trId)
    idLockingMap.unlock(trId);
    try {
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < waitInterval) {
            if (signaledTrans.contains(trId)) {
                return true;
            }
            Thread.sleep(250);
        }
    } finally {
        idLockingMap.lock(trId);
        signaledTrans.remove(trId);
        waitingTrans.remove(trId);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thread 2

```
//part of run method
idLockingMap.lock(transactionId);
try {
   // work 1
   if (waitingTrans.contains(transactionId)) {
       signaledTrans.add(transactionId)
   }
} finally {
    idLockingMap.unlock(transactionId);
}
```

Is there simple way to do this with Hazelcast?

Comment: Conditions don't need to be destroyed only the ILock that created those. Not sure if that answers your question though :)

Comment: @noctarius problem with destroying lock, I don't now when I can be destroyed. I replace ILock to locking with IMap, and write simple signaling system using Hazelcast set.

Comment: Sorry, still not really sure about your question. Can you elaborate a bit more on your use case.

Comment: @noctarius with ILock I can create ICondition for notify another thread, but I can't destroy ILock, because I don't know when I can destroy ILock, so it will be memory leak. So I use IMap.lock(key)/unlock(key) for locking, but there no ICondition for notify another thread.

Comment: @noctarius I have added my current workaround

Comment: It looks like you're asking for some "data structure" max-idle-time like feature? So the ILock will be destroyed after a period of non-usage? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @noctarius I need distributed analog for Object.wait(long timeout)/Object.notifyAll(). I can't use ILock, because It will not be garbage collected after use.